# CMake - Unable to find gRPC library on macOS

Tags: c++, cmake, grpc

I am trying to use grpc on my Mac M1 and I have followed this guide: https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/quickstart/

In my project CmakeLists.txt I have this:

```
find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

When I try to run cmake I get this error:

```
-- Could NOT find absl (missing: absl_DIR)
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:80 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /Users/venelin/.local/lib/cmake/grpc/gRPCConfig.cmake

  but it set gRPC_FOUND to FALSE so package "gRPC" is considered to be NOT
  FOUND.  Reason given by package:

  The following imported targets are referenced, but are missing: absl::base
  absl::core_headers absl::memory absl::random_random absl::status absl::cord
  absl::str_format absl::strings absl::synchronization absl::time
  absl::optional absl::flat_hash_map absl::inlined_vector absl::bind_front
  absl::hash absl::statusor absl::variant absl::utility protobuf::libprotobuf
  protobuf::libprotoc
```

So I decided to do:

```
find_package(absl CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

but then I get this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:80 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "absl" with any of
  the following names:

    abslConfig.cmake
    absl-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "absl" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "absl_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "absl"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

Any idea where is my mistake and how can I make this one work?

Comment: According to the error message you have no **Abseil** package installed on your machine.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?
I am experiencing the same thing on my old Mac (OS X 10.15). After I ran `set(ABSL_PREFIX_PATH_TO_ADD "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/grpc/cmake/build/third_party/abseil-cpp")`,  CMake finds absl, but does not find `abslTargets.cmake`, which does exist, but is located somewhere else.
Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a OSX-M1 specific situation, that most probably can be solved by really following the error-message you obtained:

> Add the installation prefix of "absl" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH

Most probably you installed abs via `brew install Abseil`, which locates it into `/opt/homebrew/...`.  Note that cmake is not yet looking there, it is used to finding stuff in the obvious Unix/Linux-places like `/usr/local` etc.

So find that `absl-config.cmake`  (e.g. browsing or worst case using `find / -name absl-config.cmake`) and add its path via

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/the/path/to/the/cmake-config/")
```

Most probably its going to be

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/opt/homebrew/opt/absl/include") #not sure about this one
find_package(absl CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

Also, generically, you should set your include and linking dirs

```
link_directories("/opt/homebrew/lib")
include_directories("/opt/homebrew/include")
```

check also [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/414622/installing-a-c-c-library-with-homebrew-on-m1-macs)

Answer (score 0):

You need not add abseil to your project explicitly.

In your CMakeLists.txt, you must have included `Protobuf` as well:

```cmake
find_package(Protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

Make sure to find `Protobuf` in `CONFIG` mode as its find module does not include `absl` and hence causes lots of trouble.

Looking for reason? Running `diff` for `protobuf-config.cmake` and `FindProtobuf.cmake` outputs, among other things, the following lines:

```
8,9c346,372
< if(NOT TARGET absl::strings)
<   find_package(absl CONFIG)
---
> 
> 
> # Backwards compatibility
> # Define camel case versions of input variables
> foreach(UPPER
>     PROTOBUF_SRC_ROOT_FOLDER
>     PROTOBUF_IMPORT_DIRS
>     PROTOBUF_DEBUG
...
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try to add `-Dabsl_DIR=$grpc_installed_directory/lib/cmake/absl/` in `cmake` command.

Or just find the directory that contains `abslConfig.cmake` and then add `-Dabsl_DIR=$contained_directory`

Comment: I am using ubuntu 22.04 and got the similar error. all the answer I found online cannot solve the problem. this is what I figured out in the end.